# How do I call a function from a shell script in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh

I'm trying to call a function `runaudit` inside of of my docker container.

The shell script, which contains the `runaudit` function, is copied inside of the image and the `BASH_ENV` environment variable is set to point to `/etc/audittools/audit.sh`

My question is, how do run this `runaudit` function inside of my container?

I tried to run it inside the container but I get the following message.

```
/ # runaudit
/bin/sh: runaudit: not found
```

The `ENV` output is showing me that the environment variable has been set.

Herewith the Dockerfile and small shell function.

**NOTE :** The real function is much larger and I need to keep it maintained inside of it's own file.

I appreciate any advice or help with this.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.10

MAINTAINER acme

ARG VERSION=0.3.0

RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar gettext libintl

RUN envsubst --version

RUN mkdir -p /etc/audittools

COPY audit.sh /etc/audittools

RUN chmod a+x /etc/audittools/audit.sh

ENV BASH_ENV "/etc/audittools/audit.sh"
```

**Shell Script - audit.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
function runaudit() {
    echo "Hello World"
}
```

**Run the function**

```
docker run -it test /bin/sh runaudit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to be an ordinary shell script; in generic programming terms, make it a "program" and not a "function".

Remember that `docker run` starts a new container with a clean environment, runs whatever its main program is, and then exits.  Also remember that the difference between a shell script and a shell function is that a function runs in the context of its calling shell and can change environment variables and other settings, whereas a shell script runs in a new shell environment; but since in a `docker run` context the parent shell environment is about to get torn down, it doesn't matter.

So I'd change the shell script to

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# ^^^ use the standard shell location
# vvv remove the function wrapper
echo "Hello World"
```

and then change the Dockerfile to run it on startup

```sh
...
COPY audit.sh /etc/audittools
RUN chmod a+x /etc/audittools/audit.sh
CMD ["/etc/audittools/audit.sh"]
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for posting your answer. Unfortunately I need to expose the audit function for the other containers I use in Kubernetes. My Jenkins CI/CD pipeline utilises different containers as part of it's build stage.

Comment: You cannot expose functions in Docker (or Kubernetes) this way (again, as a general programming statement, not specific to shell functions).  Most notably your `docker run` would audit a new empty container containing only the audit script.  Your CI system (probably the per-image Dockerfile) needs to copy the script into the images that are being built.

Answer (score 2):

you can run it like this:

```
docker run -ti test sh -c "source /etc/audittools/audit.sh && runaudit"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the CMD command and it worked fine for me from inside the dockerfile.

```
CMD ["/etc/audittools/audit.sh", "runaudit"]
```

You can add this line post the chmod for audit.sh. Your final dockerfile will look something like:

```
FROM alpine:3.10

MAINTAINER acme

ARG VERSION=0.3.0

RUN apk add --no-cache curl tar gettext libintl

RUN envsubst --version

RUN mkdir -p /etc/audittools

COPY audit.sh /etc/audittools

RUN chmod a+x /etc/audittools/audit.sh

ENV BASH_ENV "/etc/audittools/audit.sh"

CMD ["/etc/audittools/audit.sh", "runaudit"]
```